# How to create directory inside application root directory

Tags: android

I'm creating a directory and saving downloaded files inside that folder which is located in SDcard but due to a security issue I want to create the folder inside application where it is located, what do I do?

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
            "/download2/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }

            File outputFile = new File(file, "CabApp.apk");

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);



        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  
        "/download2/");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new 
                File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download2/" + "CabApp.apk")), 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        file2.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to change this path    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                   "/download2/"); to application internal path

Answer (score 0):

Check Internal Storage @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

There is also a example in the link above

Quoting docs

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

Comment: just give me simple path